# I want to access several multi-sig wallets deployed with pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0. How can I get the right frontend? Github Gnosis Safe v3.12.0?

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature, gnosis, binance, binance-smart-chain

I have several wallets that need to be accessed with the interface that was live on https://gnosis-safe.binance.org. When it changed to https://gnosis-safe.io/app/bnb I transferred several funds but forgot other multi-sig wallets with serious funds on them. Just to be clear: isn't about the second and current, new interface (gnosis-safe.io/app/bnb and app.safe.global/bnb).

All the Gnosis multi-sig wallets are deployed with pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0.

Is there still an interface like gnosis-safe.binance.org available, so that I can access the wallets? I have all the sign-owner wallets still. I can't access the wallets of course via BscScan > proxy-write page of the Gnosis wallet contract, because the contract deployer wallet is one of the standard deployer wallets of Gnosis itself, that deployed the contract when I requested it with the then-new sign-owner wallet.

Now I found previous versions of Gnosis Safe from 2021 on Github. Am I right, that I can use this to access my Gnosis multi-sig wallets, by uploading the website files to GitHub and connecting app.fleek.co with my GitHub repository? Am I able to access it in this way?

This is one of the previous versions of 2021, released in August. I made several Gnosis multi-sig wallets around March and later on in 2021.

The link to version v3.12.0:
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react/releases/tag/v3.12.0

I hope that some skilled developer can help me to solve this issue! Much appreciated.

[image: When I want to deploy the site on app.fleek.co, I need to choose for the right Framework; I think it is 'Other'; or is it 'Create React App'?]

[image: These are the fields that I have to fill in. In the following screenshot you can see what I have added.]

[image: Docker image Name: 'Gnosis-safe' (name Repository in GitHub); Build command: 'npm install && npm run build'; and by Public directory 'build' (or does it need to be 'public'?]

Comment: Have you tried connecting your safe address to the new interface https://gnosis-safe.io/app/load ? If I'm the safe's owner, I will try that first. and the thing I'm concern is which release of the contract code that I used https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/releases . I think it will likely be backward compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I've tried this already, and it says: "Address given is not a valid Safe address". For example this gnosis multisig: 0x8e567a6346c1AC50e9466c20C1b6454027c9442D. I've uploaded the Gnosis Safe v3.12.0 version, but that's an outdated release (but compatible with the gnosis contracts that I need to access), but when I want to deploy it at geek it says that it can't find /workspace package.json, but this .json file is uploaded. If the deployment succeeds then I should be able to use the interface in order to connect with my old multisigs? Or is there also an easier way?

Comment: @minhhn2910 How do I have to fix it? Because I can't access the backend of the wallet via the proxy write tab on BscScan. And because geek specifies that it can't find /workspace package.json I can't deploy the frontend and therefore also not access the wallets.

Comment: The code is ok to to run in local environment. And what is the problem you faced when you use "Write contract as Proxy" ? like this : https://bscscan.com/address/0x8e567a6346c1ac50e9466c20c1b6454027c9442d#writeProxyContract

Comment: If you just want to withdraw once and don't use the Safe anymore.  I would recommend using Remix or BSCscan. However the transaction data is a bit complex to novice user.

Comment: The reason I can't have answer is because the real issue you faced was on "How to use app.fleek.co to deploy a github repo" and I don't have account and don't intent to use that service anytime. I do have an answer for you to run the website locally and without `app.fleek.co` but you need to read document on how to install nodejs and yarn on your machine

Comment: @minhhn2910 When I connect the owner wallet to BscScan contract page, and I try to write a function to test it, it gives this error: "We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.".

Comment: @minhhn2910 I'm happy to hear how I can run the website locally; where can I find the recommended document on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is how to deploy `safe-react/releases/tag/v3.12.0` on `app.fleek.co` and it's up to the service's user guide and instruction on how to fill those fields. Since the op says it's ok to post an alternate solution to run react locally, I will post it here.
The `safe-react` repo using `yarn` for building. Step by step:

1. First you need to install `nodejs`. Here https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Use `npm` to install `yarn`: `npm install --global yarn`. Read more [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable)
3. Use `yarn` to build or run the project:

   - `yarn install`
   - `yarn start`
   - it will automatically open your browser at the default address `http://localhost:3000/`

Result: [image]

More information is on the [README file in the repo](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-react/blob/dev/README.md#installing-and-running)

Comment: Hey @minhhn2910! Thanks for your super answer. I installed odejs; then I've installed via npm command in Terminal yarn. But when I want to call npm install --yarn install then it gives an error message...